# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint while updating record in Child Table

Tags: sql, asp.net, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am receiving the below error

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK__ChildTable__ParentTable__AssocID__Layout_ID". The conflict
> occurred in database DBName , table ParentTable.

This is happening when I am trying to update any row in the ChildTable. I am updating the value in the 'Layout_ID' column in ChildTable with some value that is present in the ParentTable.

Comment: Can you share the update statement you are using?

Comment: UPDATE dbo.ChildTable SET Layout_ID = ''8902ce52-0087-cdcc-d948-e1a7751d134c''  WHERE  ID = '8902ce52-0057-cdcc-d948-e1a7751d134c'

When i run this command in SQL Server, the row gets updated. Bu when the same is done via code, it fails

Comment: Thanks, can you show the part of the code that updates the table or add it to your question aswell? Just to get a better idea where the problem might be.

Comment: make sure the value you are giving in the child table as foreign key, that exists in the parent table.

Comment: @TBA It does exist

Comment: That's the reason you were getting the error. Values that do not exist in Parent Table cannot be added or updated from child table. Read [Foreign Key Constraint](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/foreign-key.html) and [Cascading Referential Integrity](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-referential-integrity/) for getting more insight

Comment: @TBA I meant that the value do exist in the Parent table.